# Anki: Automating Image Import based on Tag number

Tags: python, image, import, tags, anki

I am currently facing a challenge in automating the import of screenshots into my Anki cards based on their corresponding Question No. I have thousands of cards, each tagged with a unique Question No., and I possess image files with screenshots of these questions.

1. I have Anki cards tagged with Question numbers.: [example tag: #Boxes::#Red::100-200::178.]
2. I have image files saved on my computer corresponding to these questions, labeled with the same Question No. (example directory: Users/Belinda/Desktop/image178.png)
3. I want to create a script or code that can identify the Question No. from the image file and import the relevant screenshot to the back side of the corresponding Anki card with the right tag.

Has anyone attempted a similar automation task within Anki?
Are there existing add-ons or scripts that could be adapted for this purpose?
Could someone provide a sample code snippet or guide on how to achieve this?

I have tried various options including AnkiConnect with Python etc. but am just a bit stuck. I understand this might be a complex task, and any help or direction would be immensely valuable. Thanks.